# Regex to remove duplicate letters but not numbers

Tags: regex

What is the appropriate regex to remove adjacent duplicate letters but not numbers?

For example:

```
p11ppppl  --> p11pl
```

I had the following regex:

```
 /[^\w\s]|(.)(?=\1)/g
```

but this also replaces duplicate numbers.

Comment: Maybe [`[^\w\s]|(\D)(?=\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/lQ0aJ9/1)?

Comment: That works! What does the | (\D) and removal of (.) do? (I'm not too good with regex)

Comment: `\D` matches a non-digit character.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it like this (visualized [here](https://regex101.com/r/vE7sS0/1)):

```
/([a-zA-Z])(?=\1)/g
```

Here's an example in Python:

```
In [21]: re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])(?=\1)', '', 'p11ppppl')
Out[21]: 'p11pl'
```

You could also use:

```
/([\D])(?=\1)/g
```

for everything except digits, or:

```
/([\w])(?=\1)/g
```

for all "word characters".

As [@Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) mentioned in the comments, we can also use:

```
/([a-zA-Z])\1+/g
```

with `\1` as the replacement string, which may be a better approach.

Comment: If you write: `/([a-zA-Z])\1+/g` with `\1` as replacement string, you will removes all consecutive duplicates in only one replacement. *(instead of one replacement by duplicate letter)*.

Comment: use a raw string for the replacement string `r'\1'` or escape the backslash `'\\1'`.